# Dynamic input values not updated in backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dynamic-forms

I have created a dynamic input field which changes depending on the item type.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
    <c:forEach items="#{tabVar.items}" var="itmVar">
        <h:outputText value="#{itmVar.label}:" />
        <c:if test="#{itmVar.isString}"> 
            <p:inputText id="#{itmVar.id}" value="#{itmVar.value}" required="#{itmVar.isEditable}" disabled="#{itmVar.isEditable}" valueChangeListener="#{tabBean.processValueChange}" maxlength="100" size="75" immediate="true" onchange="form1.submit()"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{itmVar.isDate}"> 
            <p:calendar id="#{itmVar.id}" value="#{itmVar.value}" required="#{itmVar.isEditable}" disabled="#{itmVar.isEditable}" valueChangeListener="#{tabBean.processValueChange}" onSelectUpdate="form1.submit();"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{itmVar.isDouble}"> 
            <p:inputText id="#{itmVar.id}" value="#{itmVar.value}" required="#{itmVar.isEditable}" disabled="#{not itmVar.isEditable}" valueChangeListener="#{tabBean.processValueChange}" maxlength="100">
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="#{itmVar.minDouble}" maximum="#{itmVar.maxDouble}" />
            </p:inputText>                                                
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="#{itmVar.isInteger}"> 
            <p:inputText id="#{itmVar.id}" value="#{itmVar.value}" required="#{itmVar.isEditable}" disabled="#{not itmVar.isEditable}" valueChangeListener="#{tabBean.processValueChange}" maxlength="100">
                <f:validateLongRange minimum="#{itmVar.minLong}" maximum="#{itmVar.maxLong}" />
            </p:inputText>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Everything renders correctly, but when I change and submit the input values, then it does not get updated in the backing bean. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: If I were you, I would be posting the code of the backing bean instead of expecting people to perform guesswork. Also, I would have been more specific about what values are not being updated. Usual suspects would be ids of the UIInput components in your view root.

Answer (score -1):

`#{tabBean.processValueChange}` may not right. Its not possiable to use only 1 method for valueChangeListener for all value. Can u post your full code in ManagedBean ? is that on @SessionScope ? The right method for valueChangeListener may be like this:

```
public void saveStatus(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Integer newValue = (Integer) event.getNewValue();//this is for save Status
        itmVar.setStatus(newValue);
    }
```

If you want to save a serial of value, u have to create a serial of method :) good luck!